# RxJava utility for ignoring items which are equal?

Tags: system.reactive, rx-java, rxjs

I'm trying to find the Observable operator in RxJava which will perform the following filter:

```
src: 0 0 5 5 5 5 0 0 0 1 0
dst: 0   5       0     1 0
```

I can build something, but I figured there must be something in the standard library that I'm overlooking.

`distinct` doesn't work because it only returns `0 5 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [distinctUntilChanged](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/wiki/Filtering-Observables#distinctuntilchanged).